# Get only all folders recursive

Tags: c#, directory

I was reading that once you find a exception trying to access to a directory the function interrupt and don't continue with the next directory (at least that's what i need). ¿any idea how can i workaround the problem?

I just looking for some folders to show..

C# .Net

Thanks advance

```
        static void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
    {
        try
        {
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;

            // Now find all the subdirectories under this directory.
            subDirs = root.GetDirectories();

            foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
            {
                // Resursive call for each subdirectory.
                WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            //Do nothing
        } 
    }
```

Comment: A try ... catch inside the loop would help in processing the rest of the folders.  But if one of the subfolders fails while calling GetDirectories() you presumably get none of the subfolders. You might want to take a look at the overloads of GetDirectories(). Especially the one with the EnumerationOptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to narrow the scope of your try catch to be inside the foreach loop

```
static void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
{
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;

    // Now find all the subdirectories under this directory.
    subDirs = root.GetDirectories();

    foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
    {
        // Resursive call for each subdirectory.
        try 
        {
            WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        } 

    }
}
```

This will then catch the exception but continue with the next directory.

Comment: You're right, thanks